# Raspberry ALSA sound output / input slave

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi, alsa, slave

I'm trying to set one device for playback and another one for capture, my `nano /etc/asound.conf` has this:

```
pcm.!default {
        type asym
        playback.pcm "plughw:1,1"
        capture.pcm  "plughw:1,0"
}

ctl.!default {
        type hw
        card 0
}
```

I can play sound perfectly, but I cannot record sound, my python code is throwing this errors:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) 
unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side

ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) 
Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline

ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) 
The dmix plugin supports only playback stream

ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) 
unable to open slave
```

This is a part of the code I'm running:

```
import pyaudio
class Microphone(AudioSource):
    def __init__(self, device_index = None):
        self.device_index = device_index
        self.format = pyaudio.paInt16 # 16-bit int sampling
        self.SAMPLE_WIDTH = pyaudio.get_sample_size(self.format)
        self.RATE = 16000 # sampling rate in Hertz
        self.CHANNELS = 1 # mono audio
        self.CHUNK = 1024 # number of frames stored in each buffer

        self.audio = None
        self.stream = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self.audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.stream = self.audio.open(
            input_device_index = self.device_index,
            format = self.format, rate = self.RATE, channels = self.CHANNELS, frames_per_buffer = self.CHUNK,
            input = True, # stream is an input stream
        )
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.stream.stop_stream()
        self.stream.close()
        self.stream = None
        self.audio.terminate()
```

How am I supposed to fix this error?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What program generates this output?

Comment: @CL. Just posted a bit of the code, I'ts pyaudio.

Comment: What is `device_index`?

Comment: @CL. I'm setting as None|0, if I set it as 1 it throws me a compilation error, if I set it as 0 it throws me the error I posted.

Comment: @CL. I don't know if `alsa-base` has something to do with this, but it has this `options snd-usb-audio index=0` and that's the one I want to use, that's why I'm setting 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pyaudio` is based on [PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/); all those silly messages are because of PortAudio's attempts to enumerate audio devices.

`pyaudio` device indexes are not necessarily the same as ALSA card indexes.
Use [get_device_count()](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#pyaudio.PyAudio.get_device_count) and [get_device_info_by_index()](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#pyaudio.PyAudio.get_device_info_by_index) to find the input device to use.

Answer (score 2):

The only answer I have is to buy an audio card with both input and output facility and make that the default "card." I am trying to do the same thing. I have even tried modifying the source code of PyAudio, without success. So the hardware route is currently the solution.