# Alsa issues on Raspberry pi

Tags: alsa

I am trying to use IBM watson TTS engine to play back the text. While playing the sound, I get the following error:

> ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition
> 'cards.bcm28
> 35.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0' ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned
> err
> or: No such file or directory ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand)
> Evaluate error: No such file or directo
> ry ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround21
> ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition
> 'cards.bcm28
> 35.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0' ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned
> err
> or: No such file or directory ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand)
> Evaluate error: No such file or directo
> ry ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround21
> ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition
> 'cards.bcm28
> 35.pcm.surround40.0:CARD=0' ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned
> err
> or: No such file or directory ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand)
> Evaluate error: No such file or directo
> ry ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround40
> ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition
> 'cards.bcm28
> 35.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0' ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned
> err
> or: No such file or directory ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand)
> Evaluate error: No such file or directo
> ry ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround41
> ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition
> 'cards.bcm28
> 35.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0' ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned
> err
> or: No such file or directory ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand)
> Evaluate error: No such file or directo
> ry ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround50
> ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition
> 'cards.bcm28
> 35.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0' ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned
> err
> or: No such file or directory ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand)
> Evaluate error: No such file or directo
> ry ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround51
> ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition
> 'cards.bcm28
> 35.pcm.surround71.0:CARD=0' ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned
> err
> or: No such file or directory ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand)
> Evaluate error: No such file or directo
> ry ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround71
> ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition
> 'cards.bcm28
> 35.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2' ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned
> err
> or: No such file or directory ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand)
> Evaluate error: No such file or directo
> ry ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM iec958 ALSA
> lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition
> 'cards.bcm28
> 35.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2' ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned
> err
> or: No such file or directory ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand)
> Evaluate error: No such file or directo
> ry ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM spdif ALSA
> lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition
> 'cards.bcm28
> 35.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2' ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned
> err
> or: No such file or directory ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand)
> Evaluate error: No such file or directo
> ry ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM spdif ALSA
> lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect:
> Connection r
> efused
>
> ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect:
> Connection r
> efused
>
> connect(2) call to /tmp/jack-1000/default/jack_0 failed (err=No such
> file or dir
> ectory)

My output of `aplay -l` is :

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Device [C-Media USB Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

My output of `.asoundrc` is :

```
pcm.!default {
  type asym
   playback.pcm {
     type plug
     slave.pcm "hw:0,0"
   }
   capture.pcm {
     type plug
     slave.pcm "hw:1,0"
   }
}
```

I have been trying various ways to tackle the problem, but to no avail.

Any help or directions would be appreciated.

Comment: See [Raspberry ALSA sound output / input slave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053373/raspberry-alsa-sound-output-input-slave).

Answer (score 0):

There is no sound card named `cards.bcm2835.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0`.
For this `.asoundrc` configuration, you can just use `snd_pcm_open` function to open "default" sound card instead.
https://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m.html#ga8340c7dc0ac37f37afe5e7c21d6c528b